# How to open a file with automator and then open another file when the first file is closed?

Tags: automator

I have a series of spreadsheets that I work with daily.
Is there a way to use Automator to open the first spreadsheet and when I close it because I'm done with it open the next spreadsheet?

Thank you.

Here's the a screenshot of Alphaman's solution:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *open* command with the -W option to wait until you close the program. You can hardcode the list in an Automator *Run Shell Script* action where your command lines would look like the following:

```
open -W ~/Documents/firstSpreadSheet.numbers
open -W ~/Documents/secondSpreadSheet.numbers
open -W ~/Documents/thirdSpreadSheet.numbers
```

Note that you must completely exit out of Numbers (e.g., cmd-Q) for the next file to open; closing the window is not sufficient.